# How to make windows stop from trying to download authrootstl.cab?

Tags: windows-7, certificate, code-signing

Every time I start a specific signed app, Windows 7 tries to download the following file http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab

And this trial delays the app startup.

I can't connect this computer to the internet, but I can install this file manually, if I have to. But I don't know how to do it.
How to suppress this delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go the Internet Explorer settings and disable it there.

Comment: How? (11 more to go ...)